# "XMLHttpRequest cannot" load через 60 сек. при использовании jquery.damnUploader.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Система такая - jquery.damnUploader.js используется для загрузки на другой сервер видеофайла, на котором происходит декодирование средствами ffmpeg, с последующим возвратом ссылок на декодированные файлы в HTML5 плеер. С небольшими файлами и закодированными не в MP42 - все ок. В ином случае выскакивает ошибка "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://###IP###/upload/. Origin http://###DOMEN###.ru is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin через 60 секунд. Сам аплод может идти хоть 5 минут, но когда происходит обработка загруженного файла на сервере, ajax коннект теряется через 60 секунд. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Видимо время ожидания истекает. Сначала видео загружается и всё ок, а потом начинается режим ожидания. Увеличьте в скрипте время таймаута. Хотя не факт, что это верно.

Comment: @Ярославский я бы не стал придумывать велосипед и сделал как у всех других: видео загрузилось. После загрузки обработку видео забирает какой-то другой процесс. Пока видео транскодируется, на сайте вешаем заглушку типа "видео обрабатывается". После того, как видео обработалось, программа говорит сайту, что видео обработалось и юзер спокойно смотрит это видео. Это самый лучший вариант.